# Aligning the TextView and EditText together and resizing TimePicker XML Android

Tags: android, xml, textview, android-xml, android-timepicker

I am having some trouble with my `xml` file. Basically the `timepicker` is taking too much space for a start and it is not aligned exactly underneath its associated `TextView`.

The other problem I am having is aligning the `EditText` right next to its `TextView`. I have tried moving it about but it messes up the entire view, here is the `xml` file below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="First drink time:"
        android:id="@+id/txtOne"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleX="0.60"
        android:scaleY="0.60"
        android:id="@+id/startTime"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finishTime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtTwo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Second drink time:"
        android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
        android:layout_below="@+id/finishTime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/finishTime" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleX="0.60"
        android:scaleY="0.60"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
        android:id="@+id/finishTime"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtOne" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Number of minutes for first drink:"
        android:id="@+id/txtThree"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startTime"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/startTime" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editFirstDrink"
        android:layout_below="@+id/startTime"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/startTime" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="It took me so many minutes to sober:"
        android:id="@+id/txtFour"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtThree"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtThree"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editSoberTime"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFour"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txtTotal" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="I vomited number of times:"
        android:id="@+id/txtFive"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFour"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtSix" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editVomited"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/txtFive"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnSave" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="During the night I took a piss"
        android:id="@+id/txtSix"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtFive"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtFour" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editPissAmount"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtSix"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editWakeUp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Overall, I felt from 1-5"
        android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editAwakeFor"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/txtSix" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editScore"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editAwakeFor" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Would be great if someone could help me out with my `xml` file

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I slightly altered your xml code check if its what you are looking for

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="15dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="First drink time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/startTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleX="0.90"
        android:scaleY="0.90" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Second drink time:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/finishTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-50dp"
        android:scaleX="0.90"
        android:scaleY="0.90" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtThree"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Number of minutes for first drink:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editFirstDrink"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFour"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="It took me so many minutes to sober:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editSoberTime"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtFive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="I vomited number of times:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editVomited"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtSix"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="During the night I took a piss"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editPissAmount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTotal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Overall, I felt from 1-5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editScore"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>
```

one more thing, you have many ui elements so better add `Scroll View` to your layout.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible if you could move the `Timepicker` closer to the `TextView` because there is a bit of a gap. Other than that it was pretty much what I was expecting and also two buttons at the bottom

Comment: check it i edited my answer and please accept answer if that helped :)